# How can I get the correct form of JavaScript and Ruby timestamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have this datetime stamp from Ruby:

```
2017-10-06 05:11:53 UTC
```

This datetime stamp from JavaScript:

```
"2017-10-07T12:07:06.694Z"
```

Is there a method to which I could find out the difference in seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I convert from a ruby timestamp to a javascript timestamp?

You could do this using Ruby with `strftime` or directly in javascript as demonstrated by Tavish.

```
var myDate = new Date('2017-10-06 05:11:53 UTC')
```

> How do I find the difference in seconds between two timestamps with Javascript?

```js
var past = new Date('2017-10-06 05:11:53 UTC');
var future = new Date('2017-10-07T12:07:06.694Z');
var deltaInMilliseconds = future.getTime() - past.getTime();

var deltaInSeconds = deltaInMilliseconds / 1000;
console.log(deltaInSeconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do so. One way is:

```js
var myDate = new Date('2017-10-06 05:11:53 UTC')
console.log(myDate)

var myDate1 = new Date('2017-10-07T12:07:06.694Z')
console.log(myDate1)

var difference = myDate.getSeconds() - myDate1.getSeconds()
console.log(`Seconds passed: ${difference}`)
```

Comment: `.getSeconds()` only gets the difference in the seconds column between the two timestamps (ie. :53 and :06.694).  You need to calculate the total difference in time which is actually multiple hours.

Comment: Yes, correct. Then your solution will work. Thanks for pointing it out.